# Result of the function - np.array

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

How to print the result of a function that returns:

```
return np.array([E_R, E_theta, E_z]), np.array([B_R, B_theta, B_z])
```

I would like to get E_R for instance. Thank you

Comment: `function_call_result[0][0]` would work

Comment: here, first `[0]` index is for `tuple` and second `[0]` index is for your first array

Comment: What is function_call_result, please? This is wrong for main program, isn't it? `E_R = function_call_result[0][0]`

Comment: What is your function name?

Comment: OK, it is a name of the function.

Comment: yes like `function_name()[0][0]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of accessing `E_R` directly from the function, try this:

```
def function():
  global y1
  global y2
  y1 = list(np.array([E_R, E_theta, E_z]))
  y2 = list(np.array([B_R, B_theta, B_z]))

  return y1, y2

print(function())
print(y1[1])
```

This would access `E_R`. Just access any element by the index in which it appears. May not be the most pretty solution, nor the most Pythonic, but it works.

Comment: simple `function()[0][0]` would work try it. you can access through indices